# Both ethernet and wifi adapters went 'unmanaged' on 18.04 desktop, what could cause this?

Tags: networking, 18.04, adapter

I remotely maintain an 18.04 desktop system for an elderly relative. This weekend I was "away from keyboard" and when I returned, the relative told me they "couldn't get on the internet". Nor could I connect over ssh per usual.

I was able to glean that both the ethernet and wifi adapters are showing 'unmanaged' in the Network Manager popup. I am sure that this wasn't the case last week.

Importantly, also this weekend, other relatives "helped out" with some kind of wifi issues on another device. I cannot get a clear description of what they did.

The desktop is connected directly to the router via ethernet cable, and the connections have been checked. The wifi is not normally turned on. It was after I had them turn it on, that its status changed to "unmanaged".

No one has root on the 18.04 desktop except for me. This weekend's updates look innocuous.

Could they have done something to the router to cause this?

What can I try to troubleshoot?

Comment: Could have been a Kernel update that either driver didn't carry over into via DKMS.

Comment: @Terrance last 18.04 kernel update predates this issue

Comment: Sorry I could have been thinking unclaimed and not unmanaged with that comment.  Honestly, I have never heard of a router causing a device to go unmanaged.